# Getting cell_data fielddata values from vtk file with Python VTK package

Tags: python, vtk

I have a minimal VTK with these contents

```
# vtk DataFile Version 5.1
vtk output
ASCII
DATASET STRUCTURED_GRID
DIMENSIONS 3 2 3
POINTS 18 double
0 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 
0 -0 0 1 -2.4492935983e-16 0 2 -4.8985871966e-16 0 
0 0 2 1 0 2 2 0 2 
0 -0 2 1 -2.4492935983e-16 2 2 -4.8985871966e-16 2 
0 0 4 1 0 4 2 0 4 
0 -0 4 1 -2.4492935983e-16 4 2 -4.8985871966e-16 4 

CELL_DATA 4
FIELD FieldData 1
uniform 1 4 double
0.15915494309 0.15915494309 0.053051647697 0.053051647697
```

I want to get access to that last line the "uniform" fielddata values [0.15915494309 0.15915494309 0.053051647697 0.053051647697]

I have a Python script that opens the vtk file but I'm stuck on the last part of getting those values.

```py
import vtk

filename = 'myfile.vtk'

reader = vtk.vtkGenericDataObjectReader()
reader.SetFileName(filename)
reader.ReadAllFieldsOn()
reader.Update()
#... not sure what goes here
```

Can anyone help me with the command for getting the field data

I've tried things like `reader.GetOutput().GetFieldData()` but no luck

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why but GetCellDate works better than GetFieldData

This works for me

```
import vtk

filename = 'myfile.vtk'

reader = vtk.vtkStructuredGridReader()
reader.SetFileName(filename)
reader.ReadAllFieldsOn()
reader.Update()

cell_data = reader.GetOutput().GetCellData()

num_arrays = cell_data.GetNumberOfArrays()

uniform_array = cell_data.GetArray('uniform')

num_tuples = uniform_array.GetNumberOfTuples()
values = [uniform_array.GetValue(i) for i in range(num_tuples)]
print(values)
```